# How can I convert PDF bank statements to a Excel or CSV file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, csv, ocr

I am just doing my UK tax return (Yes I have left it until the last minute). My bank (Nationwide) will only let me download the last 15 months of transactions as a CSV file, but will let me download any statement as a PDF.

Therefore I need to make use of PDF statements, so how do I get them into Excel?

Comment: Hmm. Your tax return should only need the last 12 months of figures....

Comment: Is the text in the PDFs selectable or are the jpg pdfs ?

Comment: @DavidPostill, correct, but in the UK you get 8 months to file it in, hence needing to go back more then 15 months!

Comment: @IanRingrose LOL. I'm in the UK as well. But I don't wait 8 months to file my tax return :)

Comment: @DavidPostill, we had issues with MS-Money not working, as we had upgraded to windows 10.   So destroying the nice system we had in place.

Answer (score -1):

A Google shows a few solutions.

Most of these are aimed at accountants processing statements for lots of clients and hence have charges that don’t make since for us, as we only needed to process 30 pages.

Other solutions could only cope with PDF statement that contained text within the PDF, rather than image.   To check this try selecting the text, if you can’t then it is very likely that the PDF contains a image of the statement rather than then the text.

The first solution I found is [statementreader](http://www.statementreader.com/) and we stopped at that point as it worked for us.

- They allow a few pages for free, then charge per page.
- It is windows software so needs installing.
- It is not the easiest software to install or use, so it need at least an average level of computer skills.
- It has templates for statements from lots of banks, so you just select the correct template.
- They will free of charge (it took them about 2 weeks to respond) create a template for your bank statement, even if you are just using the “free pages”.    – (As this benefits anyone else it uses their software.)
- It work for us, and avoided a lot of typing.

Answer (score -1):

Another option can be using `AutoRec` that is a handy software for analysis of the extracted data too.

software link: https://www.ocrex.com/autorec.php